# BlackBerry - How to send Email with embedded Image from Application?

Tags: image, email, blackberry, java-me

What is the possible way of sending Email with an embedded Image from Application?

Comment: This question is not programming related. Check the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to know what kind of question you can ask here. You can find a list of other sites based on the same framework at this address: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites. PhoneHow (http://phonehow.com/) seems to be more adapted to your question.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE. Only if you find a way to send email with an HTML body**. So far there is no way to send HTML email from a BlackBerry device:

> You cannot send HTML email messages from a BlackBerry device.

[RIM API 5.0 Messaging - Email messages - Accessing HTML email messages](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/Messaging-summary.html)

However if you will find a way to send an HTML email body (using TCP or if there will be this feature in the newer RIM API) then you can add an image as a part of the message content and use its content id in the HTML markup.

Your email body should look like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src=”cid:image.png”/><div>
    </body>
</html>
——=_NextPart_000_0022_01C8F277.B56CB710
Content-ID: <image.png>
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=image.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

MCaydY5mzxGm2QCqAGLObPUEAAAAAAAABwAAAAECodyrjEepzxG
O5ADADCBTZWgAAAAAAAAAZmZ4mpW9yJiHWNgOvUjZSflgDwAAA
AAAgK1DSFIlyAEqAQAAAAAAAAAcTg4AAAIIAgCtTCwAAAAC IEwAA…….etc..
```

See also [Embedding video in email](http://stylecampaign.com/blog/?p=29).

Comment: HI @Max . i had check this api but not getting How to send HTML content in Email body ? please guide me